# Why Angular layouts are not working correctly?

Tags: angular, layout

What I want is to have different layouts for different pages in my Angular App. I am using Angular 12.x.

I am trying to implement the same as per the suggestions I am getting over Internet using Routes. But the header/footer is getting duplicated.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: HomepageComponent
  },
  { // Static Pages (Inside)
    path: '', 
    component: StaticPageLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'about-us', component: AboutUsComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'contact-us', component: ContactUsComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'faq', component: FaqComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'guide', component: GuideComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'help-center', component: HelpCenterComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'how-it-works', component: HowItWorksComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'sales', component: SalesComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'sitemap', component: SitemapComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'terms-and-conditions', component: TermsAndConditionsComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]
  }
];
```

`app.component.html` looks like:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <app-header-navigation></app-header-navigation>
    <app-header></app-header>
  </div>
  <div class="content" role="main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

`static-page-component.html` looks like:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <app-header-navigation></app-header-navigation>
  </div>
  <div class="content" role="main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

The difference between above 2 is that the later one do not include `<app-header></app-header>`

This is how `/contact-us` looks like:

[image]

For me the sections `#1`, `#2` and `#6` should not be visible for the routes using `StaticPageLayoutComponent`

For me the sections `#3` & `#5` should not be visible for the `homepage` route. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your application run `app.component.html` executes. So these below two lines in the `app.component.html` file are displaying **Header Navigation** and **Header**

```
<app-header-navigation></app-header-navigation>
<app-header></app-header>
```

After that `router outlet` comes and `static.component.html` executes and in the `static.component.html` file you are again displaying header navigation so line 3 header navigation is due to this.

Same for the footer. Line 5 footer is due to the `static.component.html` file and line 6 footer is due to the `app.component.html` file.

Removing  `app-header-navigation`, `app-header` and `app-footer` from `app.component.html` file and place in each other file will solve the issue for you.